# Android and C++ Socket Communication

Tags: android, c++, sockets

I'm developing an app to receive data from C++ program every second. The app also need to send data to C++ program sometimes. 
Is it suitable to use socket as communication between both instances?
For each instance, does it have to run socket server and client at the same time?

Comment: Are the Android and C++ apps running on different machines/devices? If so, then yes, sockets would be a viable communication option. You don't need two sockets, though. Sockets are bidirectional, you can use a single socket for both sending and receiving. But, if the two apps are on the same machine/device, you might consider a different communication, such as [Android Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Comment: Sockets are the way to go. And of course the server socket has to be active/listening when the client socket tries to connect.

Comment: Yes, both on different machine. So on single socket, how do i implement bidirectional comm. Both instances have to listen at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there would be different ways of accomplishing this depending on required timing behavior (does the device have to receive messages synchronously, should messages that cannot be delivered in time be cached till they can be delivered, etc.), public reachability of the android device (if they are connected over mobile networks they are behind NAT in many mobile networks) and if the devices could go into standby mode or not.

**Using stream sockets (TCP)** if the mobile device stays awake the whole time or processing has to happen always synchronously.

In this case one end would have to be the "server" and one end to be the "client". Because mobile devices tend to go into standby mode i'd use the C++ program (if it runs on a non-mobile device) to be the server - this would be the end that creates a socket, binds it and then uses listen to wait for incoming connections. Whenever the client connects to the server it has to accept the connection which then can be used bidirectionally by using the same handle for send and receive.

The mobile device then would create a socket and connect to the server and could transmit data to it (it does not have to bind or listen). Over the same connection the device could receive data from the server.

If the server is required to send data to the mobile device even when the mobile device has not established a connection and the mobile device is able to go into standby mode one could either periodically wake the device and poll the server or use the firebase cloud messaging system or even short message service or - if the device is not able to go into standby mode - simply create a listening socket too that accepts incoming connections from the C++ application.

**Using datagram sockets (UDP)**

In this case both the C++ application and the Android application would create and bind a socket to a specific port. Then they can both simply send packets (unreliable) to other clients or even multicast them in a local area network by sending them a multicast address. Of course the mobile device would miss packets that have been sent from the C++ application during periods where it's in standby mode and the C++ application would miss packets during times it's not running.

**Using a message queue** (if the mobile device may go to standby mode and has to receive messages asynchronously)

In this case both programs would not have to run at the same time if the queues are persistent, but a message broker would have to (for example RabbitMQ). The C++ application could simply push messages into the queue and any subscribed mobile device would receive them either immediately or (for persistent queues) later whenever the devices connects to the server.

Messaging from the mobile device to the server could also be realized over a message queue if synchronous behavior is not required or over a traditional webservice or even a socket.

Comment: Thanks Isp for long explanation. It makes me clear about the concept.
My setup is simple. One to one connection. They only runs in some period of time. Maybe 2-3 hours only. In that time, the android must not allow to standby. 
I guess, the UDP is much simple for this. Am I right?

Comment: It depends. If no event should ever be missed then TCP would be the way to go because it handels retransmissions automatically and it allows to detect if the connection is gone; if events may be missed (in case of network failures, etc.) and devices don't need to know if the other device is "connected" (there are no connections with UDP) or are not meaningful after a retransmission then i'd use UDP (i'd also use UDP if more than one device would be require to receive the same set of messages on the same network because of multicasting capability).

Comment: I'm still confuse about bidirectional communication. When C++ client want to send data to Android server, it will creates socket, send, close. Android is listening all the time. But when Android need to send data to C++, does it require C++ to listen too?

Comment: If you drop the connection after each transmission then yes - then you require the device also being reachable by creating a listening socket to which the application can connect. But if you know that you have to transmit more than one value you could also keep the connection opened over the whole measurement period. Then you could use the single established connection bidirectionally.